# "dirty" function in Form, need script to delay firing until after data is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I picked up this script through a search, used for checking if any form fields have been changed before exiting the page:

```
$(':input').each(function() { 
    $(this).data('initialValue', $(this).val()); 
}); 
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    var msg = 'You haven\'t saved your changes.'; 
    var isDirty = false;  
    $(':input').each(function () { 
       if($(this).data('initialValue') != $(this).val()){ 
          isDirty = true; 
       } 
    });  
if(isDirty == true){ 
    return msg; 
} 
};
```

This works just fine when starting with an empty form, but the problem I am running into is that there is also an option to populate the form with existing data read from a database, and the first piece of code fires before the form data is loaded, therefore the "onbeforeunload" function always thinks the form is "dirty"

Ideally I would like to suspend running of the first piece of code until all form data is loaded.  I am using ASP/VBScript for the database access/form loading.

Thanks

Comment: The data is not loaded using an AJAX script but upon load of the page using ASP/VBScript.  On page 1 the user enters their access code and proceeds to the main ASP page which accesses the database based on their code and populates the form fields using a VBScript function call from each form field, this way:

__<input value="<%= GetValue("myField") %>" />__

So with this method, I don't know how to determine when all fields have been filled.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that sets the original values inside a function to be called when the data is loaded:

```
function setOriginalValues() {
    $(':input').each(function() { 
        $(this).data('initialValue', $(this).val()); 
    });
}
```

Side note: you can break a `.each()` loop by returning false. That should be done after finding a "dirty" value:

```
$(':input').each(function () { 
   if($(this).data('initialValue') != $(this).val()){ 
      isDirty = true; 
      return false;
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your form data isn't yet loaded. Even if it is coming from the server as part of page load, it may not be available until that part of the page is parsed by the browser, which is presumably after your code.

If you are populating through Ajax, you should run your function in a callback as otehrs have suggested. However, if not you can just put the code in a handler that waits until the page is ready.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/